# How to find city names in string using NLP and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nlp, nltk

As you can see in the title, my question is simple. I want to find city names using NLP. Here is an example:

***Question:***

> How is the weather today in Istanbul?

***Answer:***

```
["Istanbul"]
```

I tried this code but it didn't help me so much.

```
import nltk   
my_sent = "How is the weather in Izmit"

word = nltk.word_tokenize(my_sent)   
pos_tag = nltk.pos_tag(word)   
chunk = nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag)   
NE = [ " ".join(w for w, t in ele) for ele in chunk if isinstance(ele, nltk.Tree)]   
print(NE)
```

How can I get this result? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `spacy` package:

First you should install spacy and load the en_core_web_ln:

```
python3 -m pip install spacy 
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

Then use the code below:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp(u'How is the weather in Izmit')

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text)
```

Comment: Thanks but my PC is 32-bit Windows. I'm getting errors while trying to install spacy. Any other option?

Comment: I have only done this with spacy before but you can take a look at https://pypi.org/project/geograpy package to do this.